# Convert and expand CIDR /8,/9 to /10

Tags: python, split, ip-address, cidr

I want to change the cidr for a specific range in my python script to another cidr
like I have the ranges :

```
8.0.0.0/8
9.0.0.0/9
```

I want to devide this cidrs to a /10 cidr through my python script and show the result like this

```
8.0.0.0/10
8.64.0.0/10
8.128.0.0/10
8.192.0.0/10
9.0.0.0/10
9.64.0.0/10
```

as i know the cidr /8 should be converted to 4 cidrs /10

any help in that ? i am new in networking and i do not know how to do that at all or how to code it through python .

Thanks

Comment: Did you google? What did you find? Why was it not suitable?

Comment: Can we assume at least Python 3.3 these days? So you can use the excellent `ipaddress` module

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest to use the [`netaddr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr) module.

See its [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html), particularly the section [Supernets and subnets](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html#supernets-and-subnets).

Example:

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork

net = IPNetwork('8.0.0.0/8')

subnets = net.subnet(10)
for subnet in subnets:
    print subnet
```

Output:

```
8.0.0.0/10
8.64.0.0/10
8.128.0.0/10
8.192.0.0/10
```

Notice that `net.subnet()` returns a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) object. So you'll have to iterate over it, and once you do, it'll be exhausted. If you don't want that, create a list from it using `list(net.subnet())`.

Comment: Note that in case you're using Python 3.3 or greater, the [`ipaddress`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress) module has similar functionality: `ipaddress.IPv4Network("8.0.0.0/8").subnets(2)`, and is included in the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.3+, using [suggested by @Thomas Orozco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645852/python-convert-cidr#comment34491921_22646110) [`ipaddress` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ipaddress
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    for subnet in ipaddress.ip_network(line.strip()).subnets(new_prefix=10):
        print(subnet)
```

Example:

```
$ ./convert-cidr input.txt
```

#### Output

```
8.0.0.0/10
8.64.0.0/10
8.128.0.0/10
8.192.0.0/10
9.0.0.0/10
9.64.0.0/10
```

Comment: Thank you @jfs. This solved the following problem, whose solution is a version of your script which accepts the subnet as cmdline parameters: https://www.reddit.com/r/WireGuard/comments/u2xpot/comment/i4pogg5/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3